# Strange blackening after joining meshes

Tags: mesh

I've recently started working with Blender and i CONSTANTLY get this issue when i make 2 meshes and join them together to form 1 mesh.
[image]

This is what it looks like before i join the 2 meshes:
[image]

An this is what i get when i join them. (The magazine is not yet joined with the other meshes)
Any help on this issue will be really appreciated.
Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Can you enter edit mode and turn on the display of the normals, and check the normal direction? Sometimes that happens to me and I have to flip normals on parts or just Ctrl-N recalculate normals.

Answer (score 2):

Select the entire mesh in edit mode, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals.